# How to define global variables for Symfony2 Controller?

Tags: symfony

How to define global variables, global functions for controller page?

For example I need to use a variable "$idleTime" in almost all the functions of controller class. So where to define that global variable "$idleTime" in Symfony2 Framework?

Comment: What code do you have now?

Comment: You 'can try' to define it in parameters.yml...

Comment: If it's not subject to change you could hardcode it into one of your classes (Constrants::idleTime), but it would be more appropriate to do it as @Jahnux73 suggested....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not a global variable but, You can define in paramters.yml a parameter

```
idle_time: xxx
```

And the in the controller:

```
$this->container->getParameter('idle_time');
```